# Insert data into multiple tables from custom user profile field in wordpress

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I have created a custom profile field in `wp` admin and its saving data to `usermeta` table. But I need this data also saved in another table `'wp_ppv_performer_profile'`. This field is a dropdown field in admin.
My code:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
global $wpdb;
    $phs = $_POST['hstatus'];
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

update_usermeta( $user_id, 'hstatus', $_POST['hstatus'] );


$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->wp_ppv_performer_profile, array("performer_tags" => 
$phs ), array( "performer_id", 5));
}
```

This code is not giving errors but its not saving 'hstatus' value in table column 'performer_tags' for performer_id = 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example, make sure the table name is correct:

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields');
function my_save_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
    if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) ){
        global $wpdb;
        $status = $_POST['hstatus'];
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'hstatus', $status);

        // change to performer_profile if ppv_ is part of the prefix, only use the table name without prefix.

        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "ppv_performer_profile";

        // performer_tags and performer_id are assumed to be table columns, status is also assumed to be a string here.

        $data = array( 'performer_tags' => $status, 'performer_id' => 5);
        $format = array( '%s', '%d');
        $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Not giving any errors but still not working.

Comment: Can you check your wp-config and let me know the full db 'prefix'

Comment: Its wp_ in the database table

Comment: Then the example should work if the variables are correct and and if the columns exist

Answer (score 0):

Following code is tested and working fine for me. Please make sure table name and field names are correct. And if still not working then please debug and let us know exact error which you find.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
 function my_save_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
  if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) ){
    global $wpdb;
    $status = $_POST['hstatus'];
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'hstatus', $status);    

    $table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "ppv_performer_profile";  // Tablename is wp_ppv_performer_profile , I use $wpdb->prefix which will take defined prefix of wordpress (wp_).


    $insertdata= array( 'performer_tags' => $status, 'performer_id' => 5);       
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $insertdata); 
   }
 }
```